# How to display the last day of month instead of first in SQL query recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME
 
SET @StartDateTime = '2015-01-01'
SET @EndDateTime = '2016-01-12';
 
WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(m,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDateTime
)
SELECT DateData
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

It displays the first of the month in this format: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:mmm`

How can I update the query above so it displays:

- The last day of each month in the range
- In this format: `MM-dd-yyyy`

Thanks.

Comment: there is a function called `EOMONTH()` which returns the last day of the month of a given date [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: First of all, dates have no format, they're binary values. Formats only apply when formatting dates as strings or parsing strings into dates. Second, [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) returns the end-of-month for a date. There's no need for recursion. And even if you target a version without EOMONTH, there's still no need for recursion. You can get the start of month with `DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(someDate),MONTH(SomeDate),1)`. You can add 1 month to that and subtract 1 day to get End Of Month

Comment: Why is recursion used at all? Is this a quiz or homework assignment? Are you trying to generate a [Calendar Table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)? The link shows various techniques, many of which do use recursion. In SQL Server 2022 recursion is eliminated by using `GENERATE_SERIES`. In older versions a [Numbers table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained-part-1/) can be used for the same job

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, no teacher except pure sadist would ask for MM-dd-yyyy format

Comment: Simply use `... SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), EOMONTH(DateData), 110) AS DateData ... ` for the final `SELECT`.

Comment: The existing CTE would be clearer if you use it to calculate numbers from 1-12, and then use `DATEADD(m,n,StartDateTime)` to add months to the start date. This would make it easier to calculate starts or ends too, by changing the number starting number. The first EOM is actually `dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,2,StartDate))`, ie one day before the second Start of Month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EOMONTH` function. Note that you should still increment off the first day in the month, otherwise you can run into issues.

```sql
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME
 
SET @StartDateTime = '2015-01-01'
SET @EndDateTime = '2016-01-12';
 
WITH DateRange AS 
(
    SELECT EOMONTH(@StartDateTime) as DateData, @StartDateTime AS StartOfMonth
    UNION ALL
    SELECT EOMONOTH(DATEADD(m, 1, StartOfMonth))
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDateTime
)
SELECT DateData
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Recursion is slow. `GENERATE_SERIES` or some other numbers generator is probably better. `EOMONTH` also provides an increment parameter, which means you don't need `DATEADD`

```sql
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME
 
SET @StartDateTime = '2015-01-01'
SET @EndDateTime = '2016-01-12';
 
SELECT
  EOMONTH(@StartDateTime, g.value) AS DateData
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(month, @StartDateTime, @EndDateTime)) g;
```

The format should not be relevant, that is purely a display/presentation thing. But if you really needed to stringify the date, you can use `CONVERT(varchar(10), yourDate, 110)`.

Comment: Looks like `GENERATE_SERIES` is for newer version of SQL...

Comment: The first query returns an error: 'DateRange' has more columns than were specified in the column list.

Comment: Sorry missed that you put the column names in the `WITH` declaration

Answer (score 0):

I went with a simpler solution:

Update the `SELECT DateData` to `SELECT EOMONTH(DateData)` and that solved the issue.

Thank you everyone for the help.